# Ignoring repeated lines in a text file

Tags: linux, vi

I have a file with repeated lines that have particular text on them. I need to view the file content ignoring these lines.

Is there anyway I can achieve this using `vi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a command like `:%g/re/d` to delete all the lines that match some regular expression (re).

Answer (score 1):

Most vi clones (like vim) can read from standard input.

The following command will allow me to view /var/log/messages , while ignoring all lines from the 'kernel' syslog facility (These are the Firewall lines, which I want to ignore for now):

```
$ grep -wv "kernel:" /var/log/messages | vi -
Vim: Reading from stdin...
```

This will let you view the file, however you won't be editing the file. You are editing a copy of the file.